# match lines that end in dashes: negative lookahead not working as expected

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of text in Notepad++. Some lines end with a dash.

```
value 1
value 2
value 3 -
value 4 -
value 5
value 6
value 7 -
value 8
value 9
```

I'm trying to delete all the lines that do not end in a dash with `.*?(?!-).*?\r\n` but this is matching every line. `.*?(?!-).*?\r\n$` matches nothing. I don't really think it would help here, I just find it curious that adding the `$` marker takes the pattern from matching every line to zero. How can I match all my lines that do not end in dashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use this regex to match lines which don't end in dashes:

```
^.*[^-]$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/cH7yK4)

Or if those lines don't have any `-` at all...

```
^[^-]+$
```

The reason why adding `$` matches nothing is that `$` always comes before `\r\n`.

Comment: This is assuming that you are using the `m` modifier that causes `^` and `$` to match new lines not just new strings.  I'm assuming this is what Notepad++ does, though.

Comment: @SamSullivan N++ does that by default, yes.

Comment: Thanks for this! I know it may be a bit dumb, but I was just trying to practice with lookarounds. So even though these work, is there a way to do it using negative lookahead syntax?

Comment: @thomas Sure, it takes a bit more processing, but I would translate the first regex to: `^.*(?!-).$` and the second to `^(?:(?!-).)+$`